# Why is my network manager so slow to start?

Tags: 10.10, network-manager

Ever since I installed 10.10, the network applet stays with a red exclamation point for about 10 seconds. I don't know why this is happening. Please help me, this is very annoying! I didn't have this problem when I was with 10.04.
**EDIT:** I should maybe mention the indicator appears, but it says that there are no network available. Only after the aforementioned 10-15 seconds does it detect all the networks.

**EDIT 2:** This question is **not answered**! I have tried with another computer, and the network manager is already loaded upon login, so I know it's a bug. Please help!

**EDIT 3:** I have the same problem with my power indicator, actually...

**EDIT 4:** The problem is back once again. I have counted: it takes a full 15 seconds to load after my desktop.

**EDIT 5:** I have filed a bug report in Launchpad [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/672207). Can ANYONE help me?

**EDIT 6:** Still nobody?

Comment: I second this. I only have one home network, I'm not using any proprietary WiFi drivers, the WiFi router is like 12 feet away, and it still takes about 7 seconds to sync.

Answer (score 4):

I believe this may be an inadvertent feature of Ubuntu 10.10 by where the loading of the wireless driver is done **after** the GUI to decrease bootup time. If you'd prefer you can think of it as either everything takes 30 seconds to startup, or the GUI appears in 20 secs and the wireless comes 10 secs afterwards. Hope that helps!

Comment: That was what I feared, since bootup did seem faster. Sigh. Oh, well, guess I'll have to get used to it.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more helpful :(

Comment: No, this doesn't happen on other computers or when I try Ubuntu in a virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

Just thinking aloud here:
1. Try changing the security options in the WP. Set it to access without asking a password. See if that speeds things up.
2. If the same things worked with Lucid, then I think that the drivers are at fault.

PS: I dont know anything about the development of the drivers, I am just a n00b.

EDIT: I was looking around the conf files, and saw an option in another file, that might be of use here.

at a terminal type the following

`sudo cp /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop.backup`

`gksudo gedit /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop`

Add a line

`X-GNOME-Autostart-Delay=10`

I hope that helps.

Comment: The WP? What's that?

Comment: He means WPA, WPA2. Switch off for speed. Also try disable (uninstall) firewall on your Ubuntu host, this can speed up NetworkManager also.

Comment: I have no firewall, and WPA won't affect anything, since I can't even SEE the networks when I boot up. Read my question carefully.

Comment: I meant changing the encryption method in the Wireless access point.

Comment: I understand, but that's what I said: there are no networks displayed on startup, so even if I removed WPA from my router, it would still not show it when I boot up. And anyway, it's not unique to the network indicator, it's also the battery.

Comment: I edited my answer, see if that helps.

Comment: No, sorry. This time, it takes ten seconds for the icon to APPEAR.

Answer (score -1):

Avoid the issue, try another network manager eg wicd!

Comment: No, that won't work. As I said, it's also the battery indicator that's not working well, which means it must be rooted deeper.

Answer (score -2):

The network manager used by Ubuntu is flawed. KDE's network manager (would be Kubuntu or so) can use various backends like `wicd`, which is what I recommend to do: remove the network-manager (search related packages with Synaptic and remove them all) and install wicd.

This error is well known, often reported on Launchpad and constantly ignored by the Ubuntu developers. They used a specifically patched version (I think they wanted to integrate some of the Ubuntu One/Social Gwibber stuff into one Gnome Applet). Anyhow... it's not useable.

Comment: Okay, it's over now. I installed wicd, and it could connect. So I rebooted... only to find that boot time had increased and that wicd couldn't connect anymore! So I removed wicd, rebooted; boot time was still longer, but at least everything was ready by the time I reached my desktop, which is what I really wanted. So I don't know how wicd did it, but it seems it kinda fixed my problems, albeit with a longer boot time. Looks like Nick HS was right. But thanks everyone else!

Comment: @user3485 I sincerely doubt Ubuntu uses a specifically flawed version of network-manager just out of spite. Some bug # would be really helpful.