# Moving up network manager start time

Tags: boot, login, network-manager

A previous question having yielded no conclusive results, so i would like to know if is possible to move up the time when the Network Manager starts to be earlier in the boot process, since it takes so much time to load once i am connected. It should be ready by the time I reach the login screen, without the stupid 15 second delay I keep experiencing every time I log in!

For more information on my problem, see this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7834/why-is-my-network-manager-so-slow-to-start)

Answer (score 3):

I have three ideas:

You may have a

1. [legitimate
   bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/672207).

   The network manager is normally
   ready long before the login screen.
   On my machines, it already
   establishes connections when there
   isn't even anything on the screen.

   Now, the bug is very probably one in
   the specific driver you are using.
   I.e., as suggested in your first
   question, the driver not being ready
   before the log in.
2. Problem with your keyring.

   The `Keyfiles: Error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
   ProcEnviron` in your Bug report leads me to believe that there may be somthing wrong.

   But this is quite hard to diagnose with the available information. Perhaps you should have a look at [this bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/524454).
3. A hardware switch set to *off*.

   Ubuntu has to manually switch on the
   power to your wireless adapter,
   which happens late. (Note, this is not a statement of fact, it's a wild guess; I've no idea why it would or if it does happen late)

   Okay, this one is really far
   fetched, but it's worth a try. If
   your notebook has a physical switch
   for the wireless network, make sure it is
   set correctly. Mine has one, and it's really hard to see what it's set to. Here's some random examples from the web:

[image]

even worse:

[image]

Rather tricky to spot when these are set incorrectly. In some cases, those switches may not completely disable the wireless adapter, which could possibly explain your problem.

Comment: I think it's either 1 or 2. However, my wireless worked perfectly with Lucid Lynx before.

Answer (score 2):

Did you check "Available to all users" in Network Manager? Checking it solved this problem for me.